# error name: The method getFilter() is undefined for the type yourActivity.ListAdapter

Tags: android

```
private ArrayList <HashMap<String, Object>> availableFriends;
public ListAdapter adapter = null;
friendsearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.friendsearch);
        friendsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                FriendsActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
```

In the above line i am getting the error ,here what i am trying to do is search in a custom list view (list view with image and name)
            }

```
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

below code shows you how i am getting the list data and how i am displaying the list data.
if it required please watch it other wise leave it.

```
public List<Friend> getFriendsList(){
    String accessToken = null;
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    DatabaseUtility dao = new DatabaseUtility(helper);
    try {
        accessToken = dao.getAccessToken();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        return null;
    }
    if(accessToken == null || accessToken.length() == 0){
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        return null;
    }

    Map<String , String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
    params.put(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN_PARAM, accessToken);

    List<Friend> friendsList = null;
    try {
            friendsList = Utils.getFriendsList(params,this);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(12);
        return null;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        //handler.sendEmptyMessage(11);
        return null;
    }
    return friendsList;
}

public void displayFriends(List<Friend> friendList){
    List<Friend> friendsList = friendList;
    availableFriends = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> friendData = null;
    Friend friend = null;
    try{
        for(int i = 0 ; i < friendsList.size() ; i++){
            friend = friendsList.get(i);
            friendData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            friendData.put(FRIENDS_NAME_KEY, friend.getFriendName());
            friendData.put(IS_IMAGE_KEY, friend.getIsImage());
            friendData.put(IDKEY, friend.getFriendID());
            availableFriends.add(friendData);
        }

    adapter = new ListAdapter(availableFriends,FriendsActivity.this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListAdapter` does not implement the [`Filterable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html) interface. However, some adapters, such as [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) and [`SimpleAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) do. This means you should consider switching your adapter to something that implements the interface *or* make your own custom Adapter and implement it there.

Also, based on the code above, you set your `adapter` to be null and you don't initialize it (I don't see a call to `displayFriends()`. You should also look into that to make sure your initializations are proper (after choosing a more appropriate adapter of course).

Comment: i would like to implement filter functionality to the listadapter so how can i do that?

Comment: You will have to make a seperate class that extends `ListAdapter` and make it implement `Filterable` from there you implement the method. I haven't actually worked with this myself, so I don't know the full specifics of the implementation. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164970/android-correct-way-if-implementing-filterable-in-auto-complete) SO question gives a sort of example as well as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5381365/1815485) SO answer.

Comment: @srilatha No thanks, I'll stick with just stackoverflow. You should probably also remove the link from your comment (you can edit your comment). Anyways, I suggest you try something, do some research and come back once you have specific questions.

Comment: okay thanks for your time ,i dont have points to make upvote for u r ans ,thanks for your time ,the disabled the link from now it is not working.